# 1350 kg capacaity car hydraulic ramp/jack lifting 2500 kg car?

Tags: car, jack, hydraulic-pressure, lifting

Can you lift the front of (2000-2500)kg car safely with this 1350kg capacity(pair combined) hydraulic ramp/jack?

[image: Hydraulic car ramp/jack]

Comment: Your range of 2000-2500 Kg is quite large.  A 2000 Kg car sounds OK.  A 2500 Kg car is possibly pushing it too far.  Why don't you ask the manufacturer?

Comment: @HandyHowie Mercedes s-class and Maybachs are easily around 2.5 ton range.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a safe scenario.

Let's say the car has perfect 50%-50% weight distribution so you have 1250 kg on the front and 1250 kg on the rear.  In this case you are safe to lift it because you are below the 1350 kg limit.  Close but within it.

But it's not likely that a typical front-engine car has 50/50 weight distribution.  It's more likely 60%-40% so that means that weight on the front is closer to 1500 kg.  Now you are over your limit.

I'd opt for a larger model of jack that will give you some safety margin when lifting.  Also be sure that these have locking mechanisms or use a separate jack stand.  You NEVER want to rely on a hydraulic jack alone if you plan on getting under the lifted vehicle!

Answer (score 0):

The jack is able to safely lift the vehicle you have described. the reasoning behind this is that you are not picking up the entire vehicle only one part of it. If you were picking up the entire vehicle and it did in fact weigh 2500 kg you would be within the safety range for four jacks. One point to be considered is added weight to  the vehicle. If you were lifting a van or truck with a load or added equipment that must be added to the factory listed vehicle weight and potentially a larger jack would be required.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider this answer.